# C++1y/14: auto variable templates?

Tags: c++, c++14

Is the following C++1y/C++14 program ill-formed?

```
template<class> constexpr auto X = 42;

int main()
{
        static_assert(X<int> == 42, "");
}
```

Why / why not?

Clang trunk complains that:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('auto' and 'int')
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: A compiler bug you mean?

Comment: It's not a "template variable", it's a variable template, because it's a template, not a variable.

Comment: It works if you replace `auto` with `T`.

`template<class T> constexpr T X = 42;`

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: Hardly... The behaviour _should_ be the same, but clearly it is not. So that is totally relevant to this bug.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: Yes a compiler bug

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: you mean relevant to the compiler writers?

Comment: This looks ill-formed. The spec says "This use is allowed when declaring variables in a block (6.3), in namespace scope (3.3.6), and in a for-init-statement (6.5.3).". It does not allow it "when declaring variable templates".

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Relevant to figuring out what's going on.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Ok, thanks. I'll follow up with the committee.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Thinking about it further, implementation is as easy as `template<args> decltype(initializer) X = initializer` so it would surprise me if this is intended to be ill-formed.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos sure it is easy, and I think it's intended to be well-formed.

Comment: @Griwes: That depends on which thing is being talked about. `X` is indeed a variable template, but `X<int>` is a template variable. The code sample contains both.

Comment: @Spire, no. `X<int>` is a variable. It's no longer a template, and it's irrelevant where it came from. The world "template" has no place in its description.

Comment: @Griwes: I disagree. The original question itself was specifically about a template variable; i.e., a variable that had been instantiated from a template, so the qualification is important. But then this is not the place for this kind of side discussion, so I guess we should just leave it at that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a bug in clang, it is now fixed: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19152

Comment: Might be worth raising this on the relevant ISO C++ discussion lists, as well, in case it _is_ accidentally ill-formed (in which case it wasn't technically a Clang "bug" _per se_).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Already did: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/std-proposals/kBLBEdsKpUk - it is well-formed.  templates have an exception to the core rules - their validity is based on the validity of their family of instantiations, and not on the template declaration itself.

Comment: Yep, okay, makes sense. Seems you covered all the bases - good job :)